Raspberry-Pi 5 cron job not execute the command after reboot
I have newly Raspi 5, and I want to execute one .sh file to open Firefox after reboot.
I didn't see any error in cron status! But the file not run after reboot.
The file can run manually bash firefoxstart.sh
inside crontab -e I added like this:
@reboot bash  firefoxstart.sh
~
lines 1-16/16 (END)
pi@pi:~ $ sudo systemctl status cron
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-05-13 21:15:03 +03; 2min 24s ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 724 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9248)
        CPU: 32ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─724 /usr/sbin/cron -f

May 13 21:15:03 pi systemd[1]: Started cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon.
May 13 21:15:03 pi cron[724]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
May 13 21:15:03 pi cron[724]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
May 13 21:15:03 pi CRON[739]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 13 21:15:03 pi CRON[847]: (root) CMD (bash  firefoxstart.sh)
May 13 21:15:03 pi CRON[739]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 13 21:17:01 pi CRON[4872]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 13 21:17:01 pi CRON[4873]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 13 21:17:01 pi CRON[4872]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root

I don't know where is the issue here?

In addition to that, when the reboot action runs, you aren’t logged in yet!   Consider using .login or equivalent.

Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?
673918
Jobs run through cron, or startup scripts, or systemd scripts, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. Startup scripts are run as root. None of your PATH changes, or other environment  variable settings from ~/.bashrc are automatically propagated to  your cron job. For example, there's no $DISPLAY, so GUI programs need special treatment (read man xhost).
One can set environment variables for all one's cron jobs in the crontab file
Read man 5 crontab.
Look at the results of  echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias in each of your environments.
An easy way is to store the commands in a bash script, and execute it from your terminal session, saving the output, then, execute the script from the "other" environment, saving the output. Compare the saved outputs using diff.
#!/bin/bash
echo "=== id ===";id
echo "=== set ===";set
echo "=== env ===";env | sort
echo "=== alias ===";alias`

Since the command part of the crontab line is, by default,  interpreted by /bin/sh, which has a simpler syntax than /bin/bash, I recommend having command be a call to a bash script  (executable, mounted, starts with #!/bin/bash) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.
Beware: programs started @reboot time are started before your GUI server starts, so starting firefox won't work.
